# Selenium Webdriver: Element not visible while clicking but visible while reading attribute

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributes, click

I'm trying to click a button("BUY NOW") on the page "http://parcelhero.ennovatesoftware.net/shipment/quote?Q=93,,207,,1,1,2,3,1,postcode,cms,kgs,N,postcode,,,1&p=&s=" and getting "Element not visible" error but when I try to access an attribute of the same element then it get accessed without any error. So how an element which is not visible while clicking, is visible while accessing an attribute of the same element?

Below is the code:

```
driver.get("http://parcelhero.ennovatesoftware.net/shipment/quote?Q=93,,207,,1,1,2,3,1,postcode,cms,kgs,N,postcode,,,1&p=&s="); 
Thread.sleep(9000);
WebElement servicesection = driver.findElement(By.className("services-container"));                  
Thread.sleep(1000);

List <WebElement> servicelist = servicesection.findElements(By.className("service-block-item"));
for(WebElement option2 :  servicelist ) {              
    if(option2.getAttribute("class").contains("DHL")) {   
        System.out.println(option2.findElements(By.className("service-btn")).size());

        // "Buy Now" button element is visible while accessing "title" attribute of the element. 
        System.out.println(option2.findElement(By.className("service-btn")).getAttribute("Title"));

        // "Buy Now" button element is not visible while clicking the element.               
        option2.findElement(By.className("service-btn")).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button exists in the DOM before it is visible, so you can locate it and extract information like an attribute but you can't click on it. Use explicit wait with [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to wait for all the items to be visible

```
driver.get("http://parcelhero.ennovatesoftware.net/shipment/quote?Q=93,,207,,1,1,2,3,1,postcode,cms,kgs,N,postcode,,,1&p=&s=");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
List<WebElement> servicelist = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("service-block-item")));

for(WebElement option2 : servicelist) {
    if(option2.getAttribute("class").contains("DHL")) {   
        System.out.println(option2.findElements(By.className("service-btn")).size());
        System.out.println(option2.findElement(By.className("service-btn")).getAttribute("Title"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(option2.findElement(By.className("service-btn")))).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution given doesn't seem to work as even on increasig the time to 45 secs I got "Timed out after 45 seconds waiting for visibility of all elements located by By.className: service-block-item" error. As per my knowledge even if the element is present in the DOM it will be visible once it becomes active or it loads completely.

Comment: @user2044296 Where is it failing? and what is the exception?

Comment: "Timed out after 15 seconds waiting for visibility of all elements located by By.className: service-block-item" is the exception.

Comment: @user2044296 This is not from my updated code, please copy all my answer and replace the old one with the new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143034/discussion-between-guy-and-user2044296).

Comment: I copied all your code but still got the timed out exception I think the problem is with 
ScrollLinkedEffects. All the elements are there but they don't appear unless page is scrolled.